# How can i Update database by on-Change or by one click from drop-down list or by switcher button like on/off

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and javascript , i am building my first app, 
i need to add a currency switcher to the app , i have done everything and working file ... but i want to add a CHECKBOK type button(on/off), where users can switch the currency ...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="currency-switch"  data-on-color="info" data-off-color="primary" data-on-text="$" data-off-text="&#8377;">
```

this is my html for check box on nav bar

i want to add javascript like this -

```
$("#currency-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
  $("#currency-switch").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    if(state){
      window.location.replace("/changeCurrency/USD");
    }
    else{
      window.location.replace("/changeCurrency/INR");
    }
  });
```

(this is not actual)

But the problem is  i need to Update the database(change the currency from USD to INR);

my Route is - `{{ url('/account/currency') }}` - which POST the input data to database and Update the currency from USD to INR or INR to USD..

so can anyone do a favor for my situaion ?

i apology for my bad english and explaination ,,,, i am new ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you can update your data via ajax...
I guess you rest of code is fine..

```
$("#currency-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
  $("#currency-switch").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {

    if(state){
           $.ajax({  
            url:"/account/currency",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{changeCurrency: "USD"},  
            success:function(data){  

            }  
       });
    }
    else{
           $.ajax({  
            url:"/account/currency",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{changeCurrency: "INR"},  
            success:function(data){  

            }  
       });
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks sir .. i have adjust your code but its not updating the second value can you please check out my answer ??